# How to link QnaMaker with oneNote

Tags: azure-qna-maker

Our team maintains lot of onboarding information in OneNote. I am unable to in link oneNote with QnAMaker.
Is there a way to link oneNote to QnAMaker? I am also curious why it's not supported.

I am getting this error :-
Unsupported /Invalid url(s). Failed to extract Q&A from the source

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not a member of the QnA team, and cannot say why or why not certain sources are supported, OneNote is NOT on the list of supported sources:

[image: QnA file Sources]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/content-types#file-and-url-data-types